# Not able to start Jenkins Server on Windows 10

Tags: jenkins

I am not able to start Jenkins.war on Windows 10. Tried with multiple ports, but for each Port, getting the error that "Address already in use:bind"

I have downloaded the Jenkins war from official website, and then starting the server locally.

***Full Error Trace:***

```
INFO: Shutting down a Jenkins instance that was still starting up
java.lang.Throwable: reason
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ContextHandler.java:960)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ServletContextHandler.java:571)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.stopContext(ContextHandler.java:937)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.stopContext(ServletContextHandler.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1503)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopContext(WebAppContext.java:1467)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:1004)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop(ServletContextHandler.java:297)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:569)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:170)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:462)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
        at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:310)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:197)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at Main._main(Main.java:344)
        at Main.main(Main.java:160)

Jan 21, 2019 2:37:00 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins cleanUp
INFO: Stopping Jenkins
Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread" Jan 21, 2019 2:37:00 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStop
INFO: Stopped w.@86b455{Jenkins v2.160,/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Users\aakasshi\.jenkins\war}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/security/ClassFilterImpl
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.cleanUp(Jenkins.java:3330)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:254)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jenkins.security.ClassFilterImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:565)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 2 more
Jan 21, 2019 2:37:00 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Jetty shutdown successfully
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:186)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at Main._main(Main.java:344)
        at Main.main(Main.java:160)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:395)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:184)
        ... 7 more
Jan 21, 2019 2:37:00 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:186)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at Main._main(Main.java:344)
        at Main.main(Main.java:160)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:395)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:184)
        ... 7 more
```

**Trying with below query(an example)**
java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=9090

I had checked and all the Port which I am using in above query are free. To check the available port using `netstat -na`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Check in the task manager if there are Java Process related to Jenkins running. If that it's the case, stop it and restart Jenkins.

Comment: Is any specific process needs to be killed in task Manager as I didn't find any running process related to Jenkins.

Also, I searched the Resource Manager for the list of active ports on my system, so that I can avoid using them while starting my Jenkins server. And after viewing the list, I selected 9090 port, as this port was not present in the active port list.

Comment: @CRUZE Open the task manager and go to the details tab find the java process. Check the command line for that java process and verify if its a Jenkins (sub)process for example an active selenium thread or a maven thread. In your log seems that Jenkins did not stop in the right way.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas,
Although I didn't find any port which was active as per suggestion above, but i found port 8080  as active port. So I killed it forcefully and started the server after that, and it worked fine.. :-)